# Display X number of characters from an entry

Tags: channels

I want to display just a short blurb from each blog entry. I dont know how to display my { entry.blogentry } without having all of the text show up.

Is there a way to just show the first 100 characters OR first few lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Twig [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) filter do do this, e.g.: `entry.text |slice(0, 100)`

If you want something that looks a little nicer, and you're using the [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) plugin, you can use the [truncateStringOnWord](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/15.-Utility-Filters-&-Functions#truncatestringonword) filter, which will truncate to the number of characters you want, but only on word breaks (and it'll add an …).

Comment: I put in {{entry.blogentry | slice(0, 40 )}} but I get the <p> tags and all that. I might have to try that SEOmatic plugin but would like to try something else.

Comment: Speaking from experience, your best bet is to use SEOmatic. It is pretty fantastic.